# Question about a proof for showing that $A_n$ has no subgroup of order $\frac{n!}{4}$ if $n>4$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation

For the following theorem, I don't understand how the contradiction is derived following from concluding that $H=A_n$.

> Theorem:  If $n>4$, then $A_n$ has no subgroup of order $\frac{n!}{4}$.

*Proof:*  If $H$ is a subgroup of order $\frac{n!}{4}$, then $H$ has only two left cosets in $A_n$.  So if $\sigma$ is a cycle of length 3 in $A_n$, then the cosets $H$, $\sigma H$, $\sigma^{2}H$ cannot be all distinct.  Equality of any two of the above cosets implies either $\sigma\in H$ or $\sigma^{2}\in H$.  Now, $\sigma^{2}\in H$ implies $\sigma=\sigma^{4}\in H$. Thus, $H$ contains all cycles of length 3.  Now, since $A_n$ is generated by cycles of length 3, it follows that $H=A_n$, a contradiction. $\square$

I do not understand how after "since $A_n$ is generated by cycles of length 3, it follows that $H=A_n$", the contradiction follows.  It is not clear to me how $H$ is shown to be equal to $A_n$ from the wording of the proof.

If someone can give me some clarification, it would be much appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $\sigma$ is an arbitrary three cycle. The proof shows that $\sigma \in H$. Thus each three cycle is in $H$.

But $H$ cannot be $A_n$ since $H<A_n$ by definition.

Comment: Does this answer your question, @SethMai?

Comment: oh that is what the author meant when it says "$H$ contains all cycles of length 3".  I appreciate it. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome, @SethMai. Please note that I have made an edit to clarify things further.

Comment: I also give further clarification of what I am confused about.  Sorry, I should have been more specific.